# Excel add-in using JavaScript API - how to get chart series source?

Tags: javascript, excel, charts, add-in

I am writing an Excel add-in using [MS Office JavaScript API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt616490.aspx)

One of the tasks is to store charts in cloud and recreate them later. 
For creating a chart, the only function that the API is providing is

```
var chart = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheetName).charts.add("pie", sourceData, "auto");
```

where sourceData must be am Excel range in A1:B2 format.

Unfortunately, when we iterate through all the charts in the sheet, the [series object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt598648.aspx) only contains values, no reference to the range is provided.

In the original VBA Excel model , the Series class had an additional Formula property, that is missing from the JS implementation.

Do you have any idea how to solve that ? How to get the series range for a chart ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe provide the 'sourceData' range as follows.

```
var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
var sourceData = sheet.getRange("A1:B6");
var chart = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheetName).charts.add("pie", sourceData, "auto");
```

Placing directly as string "A1:B6" does not seem to work.